# How to fix a slow connection between web to sql

Tags: sql-server

I use Microsoft SQL Server, my web server is IIS

When the database server was on the same network as the web server, it worked very good.

Now that the web server is in one network in one city and the db is on another network in a city (80 km away) 2 different ISP companies

The new web server's firewall is open for that web and it connects but very slowly.

How can i debug it and fix that?

Comment: Find a lower latency connection between the two?

Comment: how do i do that? the DB server is on a network where i have no access to monitoring from firewall or anything...

Comment: ping between servers is ok... what else?

Comment: The answer to this is **don't put the DB in one city and the web server in another!**

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you can't fix that except moving the 2 servers back to the same LAN.

As a database administrator we even tune TCP/RSS/... settings to have maximum performance on a local LAN with VLAN's and whatever, so accessing your SQL server over WAN connections is by definition going to be slow.

Just compare copying a file from the remote location to the same copy over your LAN, and imaging doing that for ever result set you request from the database.

Without more details suggesting you have a mitigation from that I'm afraid you'll be stuck with poor performance.